# How to populate a cell based on specific name and specific date using a query function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Hello new to the forum here and relatively new to all this data business. I feel pretty confident in my skills but this one has me stumped.

Below you will see my initial query of dates, ditch_name(s),Flow, exchange water, comments. I've successfully populated this sheet to specifically research and find values from the sheet getting inputs weekly for these headings based on if there is a value for exchange water.

[image]

The next image is that of the report I want to populate. *I have circled the cell red for this example.*

I need to keep track of the amount of water diverted specific date for a rotational schedule. Seeing that the initial query for the exchange water value is specific to the ditch name and the date, I am looking at populating this second form to reflect for the same.
So the goal is to extract and populate `F44` cell (circled red) with the value of cell `D2` in the initial query using the `Ditch_name` and `Date`.

I'd like to be able to have this sheet populate on the fly if possible to reduce the errors that are associated with manually entering each dates exchange water value relative to the ditch that the water has been delivered to.

[image]

I've tried the following functions to attempt to achieve this:

```
  =query(
    'Exchange Water Report'!A1:E9,
    "select D 
    where B contains 'Winchester (D5)'" "& select D where A contains '04/03/2020'",0)
```

*-Error (formula parse error)*

```
  =query(
     Exchange Water Report'!A1:E9,
     "select D 
     where B contains 'Winchester (D5)
```

(i've tried both and/or) and `select D where A contains '04/03/2020'",0)`

*-Error #VALUE!(unable to parse query string for function query parameter 2......)*

Hope I haven't made this too confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your formulas to work, you need to modify them

**1. The correct `ExchangeDaily` named range should be `A1:A9`**

**2. The correct `QUERY` formula would be:**

```
=QUERY('Exchange Water Report'!A1:E9,"select D where B contains 'Winchester (D5)' and A contains date'2020-04-03'",0)
```

When using **date in a query `QUERY`** it needs to follow the **format `yyyy-MM-dd`**

**3. The correct `VLOOKUP` formula would be:**

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(E44,{'Exchange Water Report'!$B$2:$B$9,ExchangeDaily},2,0)=H2,VLOOKUP(E44,{'Exchange Water Report'!$B$2:$B$9,ExchangeDaily},2,0),"")
```

The function **`VLOOKUP` always searches from left to right**. That is why we need to **create a virtual range using curly brackets** `{}`.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: The slips you made are quite common so it would be nice to also **accept the answer** *(as mentioned before)*. Others can benefit as well. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @HawkT Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: _"Awesome! Thank you very much!!! I was able to use your corrected query function and it worked! ... Please read the answer to your thread! Still need some help understanding the IF statement."_ Please do **not** use the same question for an already working solution to ask another question. It completely throws future users off. You should just accept this one, post a new question and -if needed- refer to the older question.

Comment: The vlookup and if statements are incorrect and do not display the proper values. They need to be removed from the answer as they irrelavent as to why the answer was accepted!!!

Comment: **Both the vlookup and if statements display the proper values when used correctly and know what to expect from them**. By radically editing [again](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/141853/5) and [again](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/141853/6) your [original question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/141853/1) can only be misleading and uncalled for. Please read about [how this site works](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help)